# Is it possible to copy some rows from one table to the other along with rowids?

Tags: sql, sqlite, data-migration

If I type:

```
INSERT INTO table_b 
SELECT rowid, somecolumn 
  FROM table_a
```

...the rowid column would copy into new table as ordinary column and this would most likely produce an error since columns wouldn't match.

But is there a way to copy exactly the same rowids from old table to new when I'm populating it fresh ?

I know it is possible to do it that way:

```
INSERT INTO table_b 
  (rowid, othercolumn) 
  VALUES (334,  'sometext')
```

...but that needs to be write row by row instead of one line sql command.

Comment: Why are you not using a defined primary key using [autoincrement](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html)?

Comment: I am using, but here I just want to back up some columns, afaik sqlite def behavior is to make rowids autoincrement, but it would not be ideal copy if in the source table rows were deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first SQL you write is correct and will copy all information matching the columns.
You can also use a query like this:

```
INSERT INTO table2( rowId, rowValue)

SELECT rowId, rowValue FROM table1
```

Comment: It works, i forgot about the option to specify target columns. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this:

```
INSERT INTO table_b (target_name, target_name2)
  SELECT rowid, somecolumn 
  FROM table_a
```

Should work fine.  But I've not done it on sqlite...